# 【NLP】Is there a model or task that determines contextual similarity?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, language-model

I am trying to work on an engagement detection task in which I have to determine if a student is engaged in class.

I am looking for an NLP approach where I can calculate the similarity score of a conversation.

Teacher: "What is your favourite animal?"
Student: "Football."
The model should output a contextual similarity score. It may not always be question and answer between the teacher and the student, but the core idea to determine if student is distracted.

I am thinking of Q&A and semantic similarity but I am not sure which is better or if there is a more specific name for such a task.